# Performing `layoutSubviews` drawing _without_ subclassing the view, using closure instead?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

**My scenario *prevents* me from subclassing**

```
class Button: UIButton {
    override open func layoutSubviews() { // I cannot do this
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2 
    }
}
```

**My scenario *prevents* me from using constants and this scenario**. And **no** I cannot override `layoutSubviews` in `MyView`, it is just to give the example a context.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 50
    lazy var button: UIButton = ...

    func setupSubViews() { // I cannot do this either..
        button.addConstraint(button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight))
        button.layer.cornerRadius = buttonHeight / 2
    }
}
```

**What I want** (impossible? ). And **no** I cannot override `layoutSubviews` in `MyView`, it is just to give the example a context.:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    lazy var button: UIButton = ...

    func setupSubViews() {
        // desired solution, using some closure that will be run when layouting
        button.whenLayout { button, boundsWhenLayout in
            button.layer.cornerRadius = boundsWhenLayout.height / 2
        }
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to do what I want? I repeat, **I cannot subclass nor use constant for height. I cannot use layoutSubview in the view/viewcontroller owning the UIButton. I want a general solution**.

**Maybe using Objective-C *method swizzling* somehow? Or maybe using some transformation**

Comment: You could override the layoutSubviews method of MyView and update the button there.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Sorry for being unclear. I do NOT have access to that view. I was just an example to give context. I cannot use any subclasses what so ever. I need a general solution which requires the ability to apply the change _without_ having access to layoutSubviews.

Comment: Do you mean you don't have access to MyView (your example) in which case how are you going to get access to the button itself?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth It is part of a framework. The solution needs to be general. it could be ANY view, and the view is being styled else where... in my framework. So as I said, the solution I am looking for is without using layoutSubviews, since the styling of the UIButton (or UILabel, or UISwitch etc...) takes place outside of the context of `MyView`.

Comment: Could [this](https://news.realm.io/news/sash-zats-swift-swizzling/) do what you want?

Comment: over 1 year later, is there any other idea on how to do this without swizzling? Maybe using Rx?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
private let swizzling: (AnyClass, Selector, Selector) -> () = { forClass, originalSelector, swizzledSelector in
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector)
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
}

extension UIButton {
    public func startSwizzle() {
        let originalSelector = #selector(layoutSubviews)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzled_layoutSubviews)
        swizzling(UIButton.self, originalSelector, swizzledSelector)
    }

    func swizzled_layoutSubviews() {
        swizzled_layoutSubviews()
        print("swizzled_layoutSubviews ", self.frame)
    }

}
```

That is an extension to UIButton that adds a startSwizzle method that when called will execute the swizzled_layoutSubviews() just before the actual class version.